# Pandas: If value is present in one column than replace it

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to write a For loop that looks to see if a number exists in the `Pay_Day_Supply_Count` column and if so, replace the day number in the `Days` column with a `0`.

```
Example Dataframe

|Days   | Pay_Day_Supply_Count  |
--------------------------------|
|   0   |     15                |
| -456  |     50                |
|  121  |     10                |
|   0   |     15                |
|   0   |     10                |
|  323  |     20                |
|   0   |     05                |
| -444  |     10                |
|  141  |     20                |
---------------------------------
```

```
Expected Output

|Days   | Pay_Day_Supply_Count  |
--------------------------------|
|   0   |     15                |
|   0   |     50                |
|   0   |     10                |
|   0   |     15                |
|   0   |     10                |
|   0   |     20                |
|   0   |     05                |
|   0   |     10                |
|   0   |     20                |
---------------------------------
```

This is what i've tried so far:

```
for i, p in enumerate(df["Days"]):
    if df["PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT"] != '': 
        p1 = p.replace('%d', 0)
        df.at[i, 'Days'] = p1
```

Returned error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: > 6 million rows in my dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by number exists? There are null values in day column?

Comment: I think nulls are rather in `Pay_Day_Supply_Column`. Could you provide example code to generate an example data frame (also with a missing value potentially?)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I think when OP said `"value present"` he/she meant if value is > 0.

Comment: why? `if df["PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT"] != ''` suggests something different.

Comment: @Poojan - you are correct. I updated my question. If there is a number already in ```df["PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT"] ``` then replace the current number in ```Days``` with a ```0```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using boolean masking could help. Unsure about your dtypes though:

```
mask = df[Pay_Day_Supply_Count].notna()
df.loc[mask, "Day"]=0
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question. If there is a number already in ```df["PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT"] ``` then replace the current number in ```Days``` with a ```0```  The mask wrote over all the numbers in my ```Days``` column. I only want it to write over the number in ```Days``` if there is a number in the ```df["PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT"] ```

Comment: sorry, I had the wrong mask: `notnull` or `notna` will solve the issue

Comment: Anyway, it shouldn't override anything. Could you provide a glimpse of data(specifically where we are not overriding)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where` function to do this in one line :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Days'] = np.where(df["PAY_DAY_SUPPLY_CNT"] != '', 0 , df['Days'] )
```